# glut visual editor

Tags: opengl, glut

I wanted to know if their is any Glut (opengl) visual editor some thing like autocad.

Comment: Are you asking for a modelling/CAD tool based on glut? Is there any reason it must be glut based? Do you just want to study the code?

Comment: i am asking for any modeling tool that is glut based so that i dont have to write too much of code.

Comment: Write too much of code? Please elucidate.

Comment: describing a scene in Glut takes too much of coding effort, consider a case of visualizing interior of a house. If i start writing all that description in glut than it will take me good deal of time. Instead if i have some modeling tool using which i can visualize the scene and behind it also generates glut code (in short a wysiwyg editor) will be very help full.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, what you'll want to do is use a modeling tool such as Blender or Maya to generate your models/textures/materials, write out the data in some file format, then write code or use existing libraries to read in your data and then display your data using OpenGL. One example of this would be to use the Collada format for exporting/reading.

I've seen some examples in the past of converters that actually generate code from data rather than just exporting data in a format that can be read in, but its pretty limiting to do it that way, and in the long run you might be happier you have something that works generically for any model you export.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any tool that meets your exact requirements. In fact. I doubt that such a tool exists, because you can easily achieve what you want using existing tools and techniques. Most graphics engines have their own scene editor. So you can either roll your own or reuse the o/p of an existing scene editor - just parse the o/p file and create the scene in glut. Do use some kind of scene graph!!

I hope this helps!